# Error al lanzar petición SOAP con SOAPUI

Tags: java, wsdl, soapui

Buenas a todos!

Estoy intentando consumir un servicio SOAP, para ello hago uso del Programa SOAP UI.

En primer lugar accedí al wsdl y a partir de este generé el proyecto con SOAP UI.

El programa automáticamente me genera las peticiones para los distintos métodos que contiene el .wsdl configurado.

La llamada es la siguiente:
    http://localhost:9080/ConsultasGenerales/services/WSConsultaPolizas.WSConsultaPolizasHttpSoap11Endpoint/

El mensaje:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://webService.consultasGenerales.aig.es" xmlns:xsd="http://Params.webService.consultasGenerales.aig.es/xsd">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <web:consultaPolizasInd>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <web:parametrosConsulta>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd:codMediador></xsd:codMediador>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd:estado>2</xsd:estado>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd:fEfectoDesde></xsd:fEfectoDesde>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd:fEfectoHasta></xsd:fEfectoHasta>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd:idFiscalTomador></xsd:idFiscalTomador>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd:numPoliza></xsd:numPoliza>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd:producto></xsd:producto>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <xsd:tipoPoliza></xsd:tipoPoliza>
         </web:parametrosConsulta>
      </web:consultaPolizasInd>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

He de decir que la autorización (user y pass) la tengo añadida.
Cuando hago la llamada consigo detener la depuración en un filtro (filter) que procesa todas las peticiones pero como no cumple una condición que añadí obvia dicho filtro. Si continuo con el debug al final me da un error en la consola del servidor:

```
2017-11-23 14:55:47 ERROR RPCMessageReceiver:217 - Exception occurred while trying to invoke service method null
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: No bean named 'wsConsultaInfoClientes' is defined
        at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
        at org.apache.axis2.extensions.spring.receivers.SpringAppContextAwareObjectSupplier.getServiceObject(SpringAppContextAwareObjectSupplier.java:63)
        at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.createServiceObject(Utils.java:725)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.makeNewServiceObject(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:245)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.getTheImplementationObject(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:282)
        at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:78)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:114)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at es.aig.extranet.util.controlnavegacion.FiltroVulnerabilidad.doFilter(FiltroVulnerabilidad.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:265)
        at org.acegisecurity.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:166)
        at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
        at org.acegisecurity.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:81)
        at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
        at org.acegisecurity.ui.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:337)
        at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
        at org.acegisecurity.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
        at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
        at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
        at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
        at org.acegisecurity.securechannel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:138)
        at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
        at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:149)
        at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'wsConsultaInfoClientes' is defined
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:356)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:916)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:243)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:160)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:733)
        at org.apache.axis2.extensions.spring.receivers.SpringAppContextAwareObjectSupplier.getServiceObject(SpringAppContextAwareObjectSupplier.java:54)
        ... 52 more
```

Alguien podría ayudarme, 
un saludo.

Comment: Tu error no parece estar en el web service que tratas de consumir, podrías compartirnos el código java que utilizas para consumirlo??

Comment: No uso ningún código yo hago una llamada a un soap haciendo uso de la url que adjunté arriba y un XML con los parametros de la consulta que igual he adjuntado.

Comment: La respuesta en el SOAP UI es la siguiente:

    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>No bean named 'wsConsultaInfoClientes' is defined</faultstring>
         <detail/>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

Comment: Te pregunte por tu codigo Java, ya que el error que especificas en tu pregunta es de Java como tal, ademas en tus tags de la pregunta está el mismo. Y segun tu respuesta del SoapUI claramente dice que no existe un WS llamado Consulta Info Clientes, no deberia saltar ello, ya que el ws que consumes tiene otro nombre, el WS que te proporcionaron, está correcto?

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta Rostan. El problema es que el codigo java no se ha tocado, y en desarrollo, un entorno superior al que estoy probando funciona, el codigo Java no se ha tocado. Lo unico que hice fue añadir un filtro que procesa las llamadas pero como comente anteriormente lo obvia xq no cumple una condicion.

Comment: ¿Que código hay en la clase ServiceGroupBuilder.java, alrededor de la linea 106...? ServiceGroupBuilder.java:106 Puede que proporcione información sobre el error.

Comment: Esa clase es de axis2, no tengo acceso a ella.